# Python Sentinel Loop to create a Text File

Tags: python, file, sentinel

I am trying to figure out how to create a sentinel code to allow the user to input a name and test score that will be listed in a text file. I just need the names to be in column one and scores in column two of the text file. I tried having the name and grade as a single input but was given errors. I am still getting an error for the code below.

Enter the students’ name and test score. Store entered data in a text file named Class.txt, and close the file. Use an empty string as a sentinel to stop the data entry. Make sure that program will accept only correct data for the student’s test scores.

```
def main():
    outfile = open("Class.txt", 'w')

    count = 0
    student = input("Please enter a student's last name (<Enter> to quit): ")
    grade = eval(input("Please enter the student's grade (<Enter> to quit): "))
    while student != "" and grade != "":
        count = count + 1
        student = input("Please enter a student's last name (<Enter> to quit): ")
        grade = eval(input("Please enter the student's grade (<Enter> to quit): "))
        print(student, grade, file = outfile)

    outfile.close()

main()
```

error:

```
  grade = eval(input("Please enter the student's grade (<Enter> to quit): "))
  File "<string>", line 0

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Comment: "_I am still getting an error for the code below._" Telling us what the error is would be useful.

Comment: @takendarkk fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending an un-sanitized user input to `eval` - this is a very unsafe practice, and it is also what's causing an error when you try to use the sentinel (empty input for `grade`). You should not really be asking for `grade` if the name is empty.

To avoid repetition, you should place you should place your `input` calls in a function:

```
def get_data():
    student = input("Please enter a student's last name (<Enter> to quit): ")
    if student:
        grade = input("Please enter the student's grade (<Enter> to quit): ")
        if grade.isdigit():
            return (student, int(grade))
    return (None, None)
```

I added an implicit sentinel - if `grade` is not an natural number, then the loop will stop, too.

Then, you loop would look like this:

```
(student, grade) = get_data()
while student:
    print(student, grade, file = outfile)
    (student, grade) = get_data()
```

Note that I swapped the order of the input and output in the main loop, since in your original code the first input would have not been processed.

Comment: thanks a ton! I started using multiple functions a few weeks ago so I should try and get used to using that as you have mentioned. I really appreciate the help, everything works perfectly!